# Есть готовый код перевода из одной системы счисления в другую, но нужно реализовать часть кода(прикреплен) без умножения на 10

Tags: c, системы-счисления

```
int decimalToBase(int n) {
    int rslt = 0;
    int digitPos = 1;
    while (n) {
        rslt += (n % 8) * digitPos;
        n /= 8;
        digitPos *= 10;
    }
    return rslt;
}
```

Comment: Или же как реализовать перевод в другую систему по-другому

Comment: Уточним. Вам надо получить число, которое, будучи *записано как* десятичное, будет *выглядеть* как поданное на вход в восьмеричной системе счисления?

Comment: Подается десятичное число, а на вывод восьмеричное.

Comment: И на входе, и на выходе числа вообще-то двоичные :), в машинном представлении. Если вы подали, скажем, 12, а получили 14, то 14 - это не восьмеричное 12, а просто число "четырнадцать", *запись которого в **десятичном виде** соответствует числу двенадцать, записанному в **восьмеричном** виде*.

Comment: `digitPos *= 10` -> `digitPos = (digitPos << 3) + (digitPos << 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Можно как-то так

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

char *dectobase(uint64_t i, int base) {
    static char res[64+1];
    int pos = 63;
    for (uint64_t k = i; k != 0; k = k / base, pos--)
        res[pos] = "0123456789ABCDEF"[k % base];
    return &res[pos+1];
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%s\n",dectobase(0xFEED, 2));
    printf("%s\n",dectobase(0xFEED, 16));
    printf("%s\n",dectobase(177355, 8));
    printf("%s\n",dectobase(0157255, 16));
    return 0;
}
```